# flask_login sessions live after logging out

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am having an issue where after I log a user out `logout_user()` and try reaching my index.html, it properly gives me the unauthenticated message. However, if I save my session id from my cookie before logging out, I am able to place it back into the cookie and get to the `index.html` page without having to enter any creds because that session stays active.

Is there a way to manually delete the session that gets created when I `login_user()`?
I am not doing anything with sessions at the moment, that current session id is made and placed into the cookie by the `login_user(userID)` call.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're encountering [stale sessions as per the docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fresh-logins). One way to solve it would be to change the [session protection](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#session-protection) to `strong`.

```
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
```